# Why would a photoshop design show fonts smaller than in a real browser?

Tags: browser, photoshop, font-size, dpi

We have been provided with a Photoshop created specification for a website. It gives specific pixel-based panel widths and various font sizes for different items (in points).

For example, the text in a data grid is 12pt Verdana. The grid is 765px wide.

When rendered in a browser (Chrome or IE) at 100%, the grid is 765px as expected, but the font appears larger than the design (around 20-25% larger in the browser).

We suspected the DPI settings in Photoshop might be a cause, but if anything they should have had the opposite effect (Photoshop doc set to 72DPI, Windows/browsers rendering at 96DPI).

Any suggestions on what we are overlooking? Should the Photoshop file be authored at 96DPI?

Answer (score 1):

Here is another discussion about pt vs px in photoshop and how you can change to px instead. Maybe it helps :)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3868627/photoshop-pt-size-conversion-to-web

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your photoshop document is set to 72ppi, then it will match browser size

Comment: As noted in the question we tried this already. Do you have any more details?

Comment: Was the PSD provided @72ppi?

Answer (score 0):

Under CS2 its a simple process of going into the Edit Menu -> Preferences Submenu -> Units and Rulers then change the units type to pixels.